# Get new value of TextField using data binding in JavaFX MVVM

Tags: java, javafx, mvvm, data-binding, textfield

I have TextField bound to a StringProperty in my ViewModel but this StringProperty gets only the old value.

Controller:

```
@FXML
private TextField filterResultTextField;
---
this.filterResultTextField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(this.applicationViewModel.filterApplicationPropertyDataProperty());
---
this.filterResultTextField.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
   this.applicationViewModel.filter();
});
```

ViewModel:

```
private final StringProperty filterApplicationPropertyData = new SimpleStringProperty();
---
public StringProperty filterApplicationPropertyDataProperty() {
   return filterApplicationPropertyData;
}
---
public void filter() {
   var filterString = this.getFilterApplicationPropertyData() != null ? this.getFilterApplicationPropertyData().toLowerCase() : null;
  ...
}
```

With above code, the `private final StringProperty filterApplicationPropertyData = new SimpleStringProperty();` would only have the previous/old value, not the current one. I could do the following instead (it's working) but binding would become practically useless and I think it's not MVVM anymore:

// Controller

```
this.filterResultTextField.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
   this.applicationViewModel.filter(newValue);
});
```

// ViewModel

```
public void filter(String value ) {
   var filterString = value) != null ? value.toLowerCase() : null;
  ...
}
```

I appreciate your help. Thanks you.

Comment: I suspect this to be a case of lazy binding. What happens if you trigger the filter() method from a button? The fetching of the value of the bound property may actually trigger the value being updated.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. It works. But, I'm not inclined to this solution coz I want to do the filtering real time, hence, using addListener. As soon as the user types in the string, it performs filtering.

Comment: It was not a solution, just a validation of a possible cause. Lazy binding can be a real issue. But I do not think the order of binding and adding listeners should matter. Are you sure that solved the problem (as you mention below)? Or does it only trigger once, because adding the listener will sync the property?

Comment: having a binding __and__ a listener on the __same__ property sounds fishy .. design error, probably

Comment: @tbeernot ok. It's validated then. As for the solution, I guess yes. I just switched the sequence of binding and listener. Binding first then listener next. Try to switch lines 44 and 45 and it will not work anymore: https://gist.github.com/julianjupiter/97cdc2154f748ae4b82339bcdd8a2106

Comment: @kleopatra I am using the listener to invoke the logic method in my viewmodel. If it is design error, what would be the correct? Should I transfer the invoking of the method in the viewmodel itself? I tried to move the listener to the property inside the viewmodel constructor. This listener calls the filter() method. It also works. Which one is the proper?

Answer (score -2):

I found the problem. The listener was created first before setting the binding. Binding should be set first before creating the listener.

Comment: actually, no: if this _appears_ as a solution, something is severely wrong with the setup - all listeners (and a binding is just another listener) to the same observable are equal, in particular they __must not__ rely on sequence of notification.

Comment: @kleopatra I switch the sequence of binding and listener. Binding first then listener is next. You can validate it here: https://gist.github.com/julianjupiter/97cdc2154f748ae4b82339bcdd8a2106. Just switch lines 44 and 45.

Comment: Or may be, should I move the listener to the property in the viewmodel?

Comment: This indeed is a code smell; both the binding and the custom listeners are listeners, so it is a matter of who is triggered first. If the binding is first, it is updated before the custom listener is triggered. Two parallel listeners is not a good idea. Either only have the listener and do a filter(textField.getValue()), register a listener on the filterProperty to react to a change, or call the filter() method from another event (e.g. a button).

Comment: @tbeernot if that is case, what is other way to invoke filter() method? The filter() should be invoked upon typing in the textfield, so button is not possible. filter() method here is to filter the TableView rows.

Comment: I would put a listener on the filterProperty in the VM to call the filter method, then you do not have parallel but chained listeners. And remove the listener in the controller ofcourse.

Comment: @tbeernot I see. I'll keep moving the listener to the property in the VM then. Thank you.